# How do I pass a file name in the same directory into a python variable?

Tags: python-3.x, web, server

I'm trying to pass an html file in a doGET method for a BaseHTTPRequestHandler class in a web server. How do I pass a file name into a variable to access in my handler?

Instead of

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

form = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
 <title>Message Board</title>
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/">
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="submit">Post it!</button>
</form>
'''
```

I want to do something like this:

```
form = open("Messageboard.html","r")
```

But it is not working when I try to read the file here:

```
def do_GET(self):
    # First, send a 200 OK response.
    self.send_response(200)

    # Then send headers.
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
    self.end_headers()

    # Then encode and send the form.
    self.wfile.write(form.encode())
```

Comment: I'm not too acquainted with python web services - but what you do there seems a bit weird - in the form, you want to make a POST request from the form (=from the client), then you have a GET method (is that on server side?) and write a response to a GET request. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should elaborate a bit more on your question! Can you post more code?

Generally speaking, the GET request will f.ex. accept URL parameters, like so:

```
http://example.com/getFormName.do?name=Messageboard%2Ehtml
```

The dot "." in the filename has to be URL Encoded (see here: https://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)

Comment: Sure, I added more details in the question